# Android location update with fusedApi, only if am moving

Tags: android, location, fusedlocationproviderapi

How to get location update for every 1000 meter,ie update only if am moving ,with fused api integration.

Comment: Why you need it? Is there a way your location changes without moving? Like you use teleporting system? (Joking) (:

Comment: Couldn't you simply cache the previous location, and perform an action when the current location is 1km away from the previous?

Comment: Yes Dmitry is right like u have a variable name a_location_that_I_will_concider or name it altiwc then check if new location has enough distance to be replaced with altiwc or not and if yes just set it as new altiwc. Then you will use altiwc as a location

Comment: the scenario is that , if we are not moving no need to send my current location. the way is we can compare 2 latttiude and longitude and find distance , if distance greater than 1 km ,then upload to server.

Answer (score 3):

When you are building your `LocationRequest` to be used by the `FusedLocationApi` you can use the method `setSmallestDisplacement(...)` as specified in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setSmallestDisplacement(float)) like below:

```
locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(1000);
```

Note that the argument is in meters.