# Android device is stable-at one place only but still getting km traveled as more than 2Km sometime

Tags: android, location, fusedlocationproviderclient

I am developing an App into which i am taking user current location using ***FusedLocationProviderClient***. something like below code.
I am not able to understand why it takes current location as different location sometimes its ***2+KM*** far away from current location and device is just stable at one place

```
private void getLastLocation() {
        try {
            mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                                mLocation = task.getResult();

                                onNewLocation(mLocation);

                            } else {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to get location.");
                                mLocation = null;
                            }
                        }
                    });




        } catch (SecurityException unlikely) {
            //Log.e(TAG, "Lost location permission." + unlikely);
        }
```

Above code is in a foreground service... Now issue is when user device is stable yet after 5-6 hrs running the app it returns different different current location even though device is at same place(no movement )

Actual result : it should not give me any km traveled by user.
my KM traveled by user calculation is something like below code

```
double distanceInMeters = currentLocation.distanceTo(priviusLocation);

                    if (distanceInMeters > getSharedPref.getDefaultDistance() && (mLocation.getAccuracy() < Config.ACCURACY ) //Config.ACCURACY==>70{
//                if (distanceInMeters > getSharedPref.getDefaultDistance()) {//getSharedPref.getDefaultDistance()==>10
                        if (mLocation.getLatitude() > 0) {
                            getSharedPref.setPreviousLocation(String.valueOf(mLocation.getLatitude()), String.valueOf(mLocation.getLongitude()));
                            writeDataInLogFile("this set to previous ", String.valueOf(mLocation.getLatitude()) + "  getLongitude " + String.valueOf(mLocation.getLongitude()));
                        }
                        data.setGPS_Km_Travelled(String.format("%.2f", distanceInMeters / 1000));
                        data.setGPS_Is_Loc_Changed("1");

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way the fused location provider works is that it combines data from a device's GPS as well as network information from Google using the device's cellular network and WiFi information as well as perhaps other information from your device.

What sometimes happens is that when you leave a device in an area where there is little to no GPS connectivity, the user's position is inferred using network information from the device. This is sometimes as accurate as 30m but sometimes the position given by the fused location provider can be as inaccurate as a few kilometers.
Due to this your app may think the device has moved since the current location has changed even though the physical device never moved.

In order to fix this it's necessary for you to implement an algorithm to filter received positions based on certain criteria. For example, if the position has an 'accuracy' value higher than maybe up to 100m then it's not even worth considering as a valid location since the user might actually be up to 3km away from the location the api is returning.
Also, if the user's current location is too far away from the last location then the you should check whether the new location can be trusted as being accurate (a person can't usually move at a speed of more than a few km/h)

Good luck with your endeavours!

Comment: Yes i did same thing please check my code  if (distanceInMeters > getSharedPref.getDefaultDistance() && (mLocation.getAccuracy() < Config.ACCURACY ) //Config.ACCURACY==>70{

Comment: Maybe your app is accumulating small displacements with < 70m accuracy.
There is a way for you to only receive location updates if your device has moved a certain distance.
Check the following link for the official documentation:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest#setSmallestDisplacement(float)
Also check this answer for reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249408/android-location-update-with-fusedapi-only-if-am-moving